# Date Difference with formatted Dates

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How do you calculate the difference between two dates which are formatted as `%E4Y%V`? 
I want to know the date difference in weeks between, say, 201940 and 201851.

Have tried use `DATE_DIFF (DATE, DATE, DATE_PART)` but obviously dates aren't formatted correctly.

```
DATE_DIFF(DATE 'MAX(Week)', DATE 'MIN(Week)', WEEK(MONDAY)
```

In the example 201940 and 201851 the expected result is 41.

Comment: which database you are using?

Comment: My first step would be to figure out, why you cant convert it to a date object, in the first place?

Comment: Tables in Bigquery

Comment: Converting a stored string representation of a date into a real date in the query means that every row must be processed. Indices (on those "date" columns) will not (cannot) be used

Answer (score 0):

Converting these values to dates is tricky.  `%G` doesn't appear to be supported in `parse_date()`.

The following converts a value to a date:

```
select date_add(date_trunc(parse_date('%Y%m%d', concat(substr(yyyymm, 1, 4), '0601')), isoyear),
                 interval mod(cast(yyyymm as int64), 100) week
                )
```

You can get the difference as:

```
select date_diff(date_add(date_trunc( parse_date('%Y%m%d', concat(substr(yyyymm1, 1, 4), '0601')), isoyear),
                          interval mod(cast(yyyymm1 as int64), 100) week
                         ),
                 date_add(date_trunc( parse_date('%Y%m%d', concat(substr(yyyymm2, 1, 4), '0601')), isoyear),
                          interval mod(cast(yyyymm2 as int64), 100) week
                         ),
                 day
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
DATE_DIFF(PARSE_DATE("%E4Y%V", "201940"), PARSE_DATE("%E4Y%V", "201851"), WEEK(MONDAY))
```